# Which online test should I take or any method to know, how much knowledge I acquire as web designer?

Tags: html, web-development, css, website-design, layout

Which online test should I take or any method to know, how much knowledge I acquire as web designer?

Both.

**1. Practical knowledge**

&

**2.theoretical knowledge.**

Answer (score 1):

The best test is to **make** a website. I didn't see a url in your profile so start creating a website for yourself.

Start with a design you created in a graphics application. Code the HTML, add the CSS (bonus points if you use responsive design), add some javascript to make it a bit interactive. If you also know a server-side language then add features so you can easily add and update pages, upload new pictures/documents, have a contact form that sends an email.

If you get stuck somewhere search for a solution and you will learn your shortcomings automatically and solve them at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. However, I should had asked "how do I know, that how much I have fared as a web designer in terms of web designing trends"?

Comment: The trends change almost every day. You will never stop learning. Just make a website and ask people for feedback.